# yum update httpd failed on CentOS 7

Tags: apache, updates, centos7, yum

I am trying to update Cent OS 7.2 box for compliance activities. It is failing with error "error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/suexec;5a02e28f: cpio: cap_set_file" as below,

```
15-186 ~# yum update httpd        
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.scalabledns.com
 * epel: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * extras: ftp.usf.edu
 * updates: ftp.usf.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-40.el7.centos will be updated
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Arch                                                  Version                                                              Repository                                              Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 httpd                                                x86_64                                                2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6                                                updates                                                2.7 M

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total download size: 2.7 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                 | 2.7 MB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                         1/2 
Error unpacking rpm package httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/sbin/suexec;5a02e28f: cpio: cap_set_file
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                           1/2 
  Verifying  : httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                         2/2 

Failed:
  httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-40.el7.centos                                                                                   httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6                                                                                  

Complete!
```

It worked on another similar box. Checked many blogs and redhat bugzilla but no way out. Anybody has any clue whats happening here?

Comment: Did you run it as root?

Comment: Yes. I did run it as root. It has worked on one box but failed on other.

Comment: Finally reinstalled the latest OS for this box. this work around the issue but did not get the actual fix.

Comment: Did you also had this line on the other box: `Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.`?

Answer (score 0):

It's a moby issue - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6980. Try to change docker storage driver/host OS.

Comment: It might be... but otoh I get a very similar error now: **error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/httpd/run: cpio: rename
httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!** And docker/etc. has absolutely nothing to do with my box. I looked for the srpm but of course unavailable (quick look) which means I can't fix the script. I find CentOS bug reporting form really annoying so I've been waiting. In my case it creates a symlink e.g. **run;5b084768 -> /run/httpd** - each and every failed update.